# Finding the intersect between a quadratic and a line

Tags: geometry, polynomials, quadratics, graphing-functions, python

I am trying to find the intersect between a straight line and a quadratic curve, however the result I am getting appears to be imaginary although I don't see how this can be the case as I can see them intersect on real axes:

```
Import numpy
#quadratic coefficients



a,b,c = (-3.09363812e-04, 1.52138019e+03, -1.87044961e+09)

# y = ax^2 + bx + c



#line coefficients

m,d = (1.06446434e-03, -2.61660911e+03)

#y = mx + d



intersect = (-(b-m)+((b-m)**2 - 4*a*(c-d))**0.5)/(2*a)

print(intersect)
```

The output of this is 2458883.4674943495-107.95731226786134j

I am trying to find the intersect between the yellow curve over the blue points and the black dotted line

[image]

Comment: Your graph is wrong: the ordinate of the vertex is $-2.82$.

Comment: So this is a problem I was having earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60831187/using-numpy-polyfit Does this mean that The coefficients are wrong for the graph then?

Comment: Although how can they be wrong if they are fitting correctly over the points

Comment: I cannot comment on software issues, but the parabola in your graph is NOT that with equation $y=ax^2+bx+c$, for the given values of $(a,b,c)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the correct graphs of the parabola and line described in the question. Definitely different from those shown above. As you can see, line and parabola do not intersect.

[image]

Comment: Does that mean the graph plotted is the imaginary graph of the parabola?

Comment: I used "real" instead of "correct", sorry.